# Is it possible to get launching event of Applications in android?

Tags: android, kill-process, long-running-processes

I am developing an application which shows some specific allowed apps.If user tried to launch except these allowed apps i want to block them.

I know that it is possible to get running  tasks using **ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(..)** and checked their package names.But RunningTask information gets only after launching of apps.Because of that when i am trying device back button , launches blocked application which is previously run and I am unable to continue.

How to prevent launching of blocked apps before their launch? Any help - much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately you can't block launching of applications.
You can prepare a custom Launcher application which shows only allowed apps.

Comment: How can i remove the blocked application from stack if they launched because when i pressed device back button,shows the activity of blocked application.